# Replacing a value on a dataframe based on values on another dataframe using index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df1 with the following values:

```
Vehicle1  Vehicle2 Vehicle3
   0         0         0   
   1         3         2
   0         0         4
  NaN       NaN        0
```

and a df2 with the values:

```
Index         Coords
  0    (-49.36204, -21.04797)
  1    (-48.9062, -20.7399)
  2    (-48.9132, -20.7296)
  3    (-48.8955, -20.7329)
  4    (-48.8065, -20.8147)
```

I want to replace the values in df1 for the values in the df['Coords'] using the column df['index'] as a reference, so I'll get something like this:

```
      Vehicle1              Vehicle2              Vehicle3
(-49.36204,-21.04797)  (-49.36204,-21.04797)    (-49.36204,-21.04797)
(-48.9062,-20.7399)    (-48.8955, -20.7329)     (-48.9132, -20.7296)
(-49.36204,-21.04797)  (-49.36204,-21.04797)    (-48.8065, -20.8147)
       NaN                     NaN              (-49.36204,-21.04797)
```

Comment: Is `Index` a column of df2 or the actual index?

Comment: @Derek O It's a column!

Comment: Okay cool - hopefully my answer works then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Index` is a column in df2, you can use `applymap` to apply a function to each element of df1:

```
df1.applymap(lambda x: df2[df2['Index'] == int(x)].Coords.values[0], na_action='ignore')
```

Result:

```
                 Vehicle1                Vehicle2                Vehicle3
0  (-49.36204, -21.04797)  (-49.36204, -21.04797)  (-49.36204, -21.04797)
1    (-48.9062, -20.7399)    (-48.8955, -20.7329)    (-48.9132, -20.7296)
2  (-49.36204, -21.04797)  (-49.36204, -21.04797)    (-48.8065, -20.8147)
3                     NaN                     NaN  (-49.36204, -21.04797)
```